# Bookmarks parsing issue

Tags: parsing, bookmarks

I have a LARGE number of bookmarks and wanted to export them and share them with a group I work with. The issue is that when I export them, there are ADD_DATE and LAST_MODIFIED fields added by the browser (Firefox).  I was hoping to just use cut or awk to pull the fields I want but the lack of a space before the >(website_name) is making that difficult. And my regex skills are weak.

How do I add a single space before the second to last > at the end of the line so that I can use cut or awk to pull out the fields I want into a new file?

Ex: 123456">SecurityTrails  would become  123456 >SecurityTrails

Please see below for examples of what I'm working with. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<DT><A HREF="https://securitytrails.com/" ADD_DATE="1586881447" LAST_MODIFIED="1612650221">SecurityTrails</A>
```

Comment: It might be easier to use Javascript (if thats in your skillset). If you're set on a regex approach, I'd recommend playing around on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/). Its great for testing regexes & tells you a lot about whats what.

Comment: A better example could help someone give you a solve though. Using code blocks in your answer to show input data, actual output of your current approach, and the desired output. Also if you could share the regex or awk that you're using. & Welcome to SO! :) You did give some example, but its hard for me to understand exactly what you need as its currently presented.

Answer (score 0):

i use firefox myself. it frequently also embeds favicon into the exported bookmarks.html file via base64 encoding. so to account for the different scenarios (than just the one mentioned by OP), maybe something like

```
{mawk/mawk2/gawk} 'BEGIN { FS = "\042" } $1 = $1'
```

then do whatever cutting that you want. That's just assuming OP wanted to keep every bit of it, and simply remove the quotations.

Now, if the objective is just to take out URL+Name of it,

```
{mawk/mawk2/gawk} 'BEGIN { DBLQT="\042"; FS = "(<A HREF=" DBLQT "|>)" } /<A HREF=/ {

             url = substr($2, 1, index($2, DBLQT) - 1);   
        sitename = $(NF-1); 

        sub(/<\/A$/, "", sitename) ;         
        print url " > "  sitename  ; }'       # or whatever way you want the output to be
```

I just typed it in extra verbosity to show what `\042` meant - the ascii octal for double quote.